# complex expression that gives 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the most complex(meaning complicated not meaning complex numbers or variables ) expression in Math that gives 1. An expression using all the math you know of and then make it as complex as you can

Comment: Why get into that trouble? Is there any specific reason? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: I'm sorry that people have been downvoting your question but no one has told you why.  Your question doesn't seem well formulated.  To me, I can't understand it unless you tell me what you mean by the word complex.  And even then, how do you judge an expression's complexity? These are issues that need to be addressed clearly for your question to make sense.

Comment: how far would you go to make an expression like it?it can serve as a new topic to discuss and many more

Comment: @user46944  complex meaning just a random expression which is complicated not adressing complex numbers or variables

Comment: @ramu But what does complicated mean?  Do you mean cluttered instead?  Do you want something that superficially looks highly technical, but can really be simply reduced?  That's what the answer already posted does.

Comment: @user46944 i just need an expression not a proof. answers may vary just that how could you make something that complex and just be 1 at the end

Comment: There is no limit to the complexity possible. If you find three distinct expressions $a,b,c$ that equal $1$, then $a^{b-c}=1^0=1$ as well, and this is (probably) considered more complex than any of its constituents.

Comment: @Ramu This question is far too broad, you need to refine it much more to make it salvageable

Comment: Why is it tagged [tag:elementary-number-theory]?  Are you saying that answers are only limited to this field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $a$ be the most complex valid expression equal to one. consider $b:=\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}2^{-i}}}$ clearly $b$ is more complex than $a$. thus such an expression can not exist :-)

Comment: Why is this answer receiving upvotes?  What does complex mean?

Comment: @user46944 I believe the OP meant to say "complicated" or "long" when he said  "complex". In that sense, this answer perfectly answers the question.

Comment: @5xum I don't see how $b$ here is "complicated" -- whatever that means.  The answerer wrote the square root of a fraction where the numerator is the sum of $1$ and a representation of $1$, and the denominator is a representation of $2$.

Comment: @5xum Unless the purpose of the question is to find different representations of $1$ and combine them to get $1$.

Comment: @user46944 That's the whole point. If $a$ is a complicated expression that represents $1$, then $b$ is also an expression that represents $1$, and it is more complicated than $a$. "Complicated" is not a strict mathematical term, but it looks like most people agree that the more things in the expression, the more complicated the expression.

Comment: ok, I don't understand. Why you give upvotes to this answer and downvotes for the question? where are your logic?

Comment: @LuisFelipe I think there are two groups, one giving upvotes and the other downvotes. I upvoted the answer because this answer very nicely explains why the question itself is bad, but some other user might think that the question is bad and just give it a downvote.

Comment: is bad because if the question has "No sense" then the answer with the same idea of the question must have "no sense". so here people have double moral: the answer is 'stupid' because is too easy for me and I'm so ´stupid´and can't figure out what he means for "complex" but i'm too smart  and this answer seems fine so, doesn't matter what means "complex" in the question because I understand what means "complex" in the answer. bad bad bad bad